# Why can't HDFS use the remaining good data-nodes in its pipeline recovery process?

Tags: hdfs

**Question**

Why can't HDFS use the remaining good data-nodes in its pipeline recovery process

**Setup**

- We have 5 Data Notes in our HDFS cluster.
- We have replication factor of 3.
- We have set dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy to DEFAULT
- One of the Data Nodes is taken down when a write is in progress.
- There are 4 remaining Data Nodes in our HDFS cluster.

**Exception**

- We see an **ERROR** log statement with the following exception

> ```
> > java.io.IOException: Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing
> > pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try. (Nodes:
> > current=[DatanodeInfoWithStorage[xxx.xxx.xxx.65:xxxx,DS-0ea7ee77-34e2-41e1-9343-50c373fe08e1,DISK],
> > DatanodeInfoWithStorage[xxx.xxx.xxx.61:xxxx,DS-894ff0a4-9906-499a-919d-4af136208502,DISK]],
> > original=[DatanodeInfoWithStorage[xxx.xxx.xxx.65:xxxx,DS-0ea7ee77-34e2-41e1-9343-50c373fe08e1,DISK],
> > DatanodeInfoWithStorage[xxx.xxx.xxx.61:xxxx,DS-894ff0a4-9906-499a-919d-4af136208502,DISK]]).
> > The current failed datanode replacement policy is DEFAULT, and a
> > client may configure this via
> > 'dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy' in its
> > configuration.
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.findNewDatanode(DataStreamer.java:1304)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.addDatanode2ExistingPipeline(DataStreamer.java:1372)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.handleDatanodeReplacement(DataStreamer.java:1598)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.setupPipelineInternal(DataStreamer.java:1499)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery(DataStreamer.java:1481)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.processDatanodeOrExternalError(DataStreamer.java:1256)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:667)
> ```

I see no exceptions in the name node at this time.

Please do not respond by asking me to change `dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy` unless it will force HDFS to use the remaining good nodes.

I like to understand why my observations do not match expected behaviour of HDFS.

---

- I have looked at the code and it looks like the `ClientProtocol` implementation is sending back the set of nodes that are currently being used in the pipeline.
- `DataStreamer`class throws this exception because the length of the nodes currently being used in the piplein is the same suggested set of nodes.